# Copy cell text to clipboard whith multiselect

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am trying to find a way to copy cell content to clipboard in Kendo Grid HTML.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

Set grid event

```
dataBound: function onDataBound(e) {
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
$(grid.tbody).on("click", "td", function (e) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var colIdx = $("td", row).index(this);
    copyToClipboard(row ,colIdx);
});
}
```

And function to get and copy value

```
copyToClipboard=function(grid ,row ,idx){
var colName = grid.options.columns[idx].field;
var value= grid.dataItem(row)[colName];
window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", value);
}
```

I dont test it. May be there is better way to retrive cell value by row and column